# Hitting Trello API for Cucumber testing experience and stuck on trying to get the state of the test Trello board reset

Tags: rest, automated-tests, cucumber, specflow

I have written the following Cucumber feature/scenario targeting the Trello REST API:

```
Feature: Change existing board details
    In order to keep my boards up to date
    As Trello member
    I want to be able to edit board details

Scenario: Update the board name
    Given I have an existing board with id 59f8c6debdf037ee708c302f
    When I request to update the name
    Then the name of the board should change
```

However, once I run through my tests, any subsequent test runs will fail because the board name is never reset to its initial state, and I'm asserting that it matches the initial name here (but after running my tests it will change to the updated name):

```
    [Given("I have an existing board with id (.*)")]
    public void GivenIHaveAnExistingBoard(string id)
    {
        request = restHelper.GetBoard(id);

        if (request.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Board>(request.Content);
            testBoardId = board.Id;
            Assert.That(board.Name, Is.EqualTo(initialBoardName)); 
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.Write(String.Format("Request unsuccessful with status code {0}", request.StatusCode));
        }
    }
```

I started writing another Given step that sets the board name to the initial name before running the test, but I realized I am then using the REST query I'm testing (a `PUT` request to the endpoint to rename a board) in my setup. This seems... wrong. Is there a better way to ensure my test Trello board returns to a default state before running tests?

Comment: Another option would be to have some cleanup code on a Before Hook but a PUT request to the Trello API would still be required to revert the board name to the original value. You could write a new PUT request on the test code to keep the method under test isolated from the cleanup code but this would create some code duplication...

Comment: Why are you testing the Trello API? Surely Trello test the API themselves. Testing external service isn't something Cucumber is designed for, so you might be using the wrong tool for the job or you may not need to do the job at all!

Comment: @diabolist I'm trying out different mechanisms for testing third-party software via APIs. I'm not trying to test for Trello, it was just a free and well documented option. :) Your second point - testing external services not being a good fit for Cucumber - is basically exactly what I was gauging. On that note, do you have any suggestions for other options to facilitate non-technical and technical people working together to create tests for third-party software they might be using (solutions-level testing, not unit)?

Comment: I think the question about working together to create tests for third party software might be worth a separate question. I'd be interested to know why technical and non-technical people would get together to do this, and why you feel automated tests are needed for such a service.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is a tool for driving the development of software, not a tool for testing existing software and even less a tool for testing someone else's software, and even less a tool for testing an existing api.

You can use Cucumber in a couple of ways to test your own API's. You can apply an abstract approach and talk in general business language about the services available, or you can write scenarios that talk about request codes and return values (I greatly prefer the first approach, if you are doing the second you might as well write unit tests).

A general approach when interacting with API's that are not under your control is to record responses so you can avoid the problem of your actions changing data and resulting responses. A tool like VCR (https://github.com/vcr/vcr) is worth reading about.

Another approach is to not do any write testing at all, make all your tests read only.

Any automated test of an external api that actually call the api run risk of being very flakey because:

1. the api may not be available
2. the api may get really annoyed with you repeatedly calling it
3. any write to the api may have cascading effects on subsequent reads of the api
4. a write may not be undoable

So generally with Cukes you would be working with your own api, or writing features for your software that uses an external api.